# Enum or a properties file for URLs?

Tags: enums, properties-file

I am looking for suggestions on what the best practice is for declaring URLs. Property files or enum? 
Edit : I use Java as my programming language.

Comment: unclear, please edit question. What programming language ? To do what ? in which context ?

Comment: You can take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864720/properties-or-enums-or-static-final

Answer (score 1):

Use hardwired constants in your Java code when you don't want users / deployers / testers / tests changing them.

Use a properties file when you do want this to be a possibility.

The point is that changing a hard-wired constant in your application's source code entails editing the source code, rebuilding and redeploying. By contrast, changing a properties file may be as simple as firing up NotePad.

Constants - when you don't mind re-compiling the application each time you change value. Sort of an irony here. Why would you change something if it has been called a constant :)

Properties file - when you want the luxury of just changing the value and maybe restarting the application to pick up the change.